# Change variable in views.py after model.method worked - Django

Tags: python, django

everyone.

I have a global variable in views.py: it is a list of users who voted.

I want to empty that list, after my Author is deleted.

I have a Author.delete method in models.py, which I could use to empty it, but I can't import a list to models.py

views.py

```
voted_list=[]
```

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Option.objects.filter(author_id=self.id).update(author_id=None, votes=0)
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or may I import my 'delete' method to views, something like:

views.py

```
if Author.delete():
    voted_list=[]
```

***EDIT***
I needed to be more clear with my question. I have a method in views: def

```
vote(request, author_id):
    global voted_list
    author = get_object_or_404(Author, pk=author_id)
    a= LogEntry.objects.log_action(
    user_id         = request.user.pk, 
    content_type_id = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Option).pk,
    object_id       = Option.pk,
    object_repr     = force_text(Option), 
    action_flag     = CHANGE
)
    print("Voted:",a.user_id)
    voted_list.append(User.objects.get(pk=a.user_id))
```

I just want to pass to a template list of user_id who voted. But after a deletion of Author empty it. I dont want to use db changes, because in my current state I think i've overcomplicated them

Thank you.

Comment: Please do *not* use a global list in the first place. Normally a webserver is not supposed to maintain a (global) state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please be aware that it is a bad practice to have global variables for such use.

You code looks a bit weird in my opinion: when you delete an `Author` (which object I assume is a foreign key for `Option`?), then automatically it sets the value of this `ForeignKeyField` to `None`. So, setting manually `author_id=None` does not feel right (it is like you are doing something not required).

What does `voted_list` relate to?

Something I would suggest is to set for each class you need to know who voted for (is that `Option`?), a `ManyToManyField` called `authors_who_voted_for` (for instance), and add manually any `Author` instance who actually voted for said Object. That way, if one `Author` is to be deleted, it will be automatically removed from `authors_who_voted_for`. Wouldn't that be a better solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem using LogEntry function